# Get the default cluster size for NTFS

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, filesystems, ntfs, cluster

I try to determine the default cluster size for NTFS. I check [this table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/default-cluster-size-for-ntfs-fat-and-exfat-9772e6f1-e31a-00d7-e18f-73169155af95#:%7E:text=Cluster%20size%20represents%20the%20smallest,multiple%20of%20the%20cluster%20size).

The problem is when the size in the boundary, for example:

2 TB–16 TB: 4kb
16TB–32 TB: 8kb

Then what will be the cluster size for 16TB? It is difficult to find a disk that exactly match the size boundary to make the test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Microsoft NTFS Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/ntfs-overview)

> With (2^32 – 1) clusters (the maximum number of clusters that NTFS supports), the following volume and file sizes are supported.

That means a maximum of 4,294,967,295 4kB clusters for a total of 17,179,869,180kB (16TB - 4kB) of data.

The "boundary" you are looking for is, quite literally, 16TB. Below 16TB will have 4kB clusters while 16TB and above will have 8kB clusters.

Above that partition size NTFS would switch to 8KB clusters.

Comment: “while 16TB and above will have 8kB clusters.” - Documentation says that’s only true up to 32 TB (I.e between 16 TB and 32 TB)

Comment: @Ramhound indeed, but OP was specifically asking where the boundary was from 4kB to 8kB. Given the limit of (2^32 – 1) clusters it is a simple question of mathematics to calculate the following boundaries, or it can be simply multiplied up by 2 to find them

Answer (score 0):

the answer is to use a simple command line with powershell

Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Volume | Select-Object -Property Name, Label, BlockSize

The blockSize is in Bytes